# Is there any high performance POSIX-like filesystem without a single point of failure?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, distributed-system

We have a web service that needs a somewhat POSIX-compatible shared filesystem for the application servers (multiple redundant systems running in parallel behind redundant load balancers). We're currently running GlusterFS as the shared filesystem for the application servers but I'm not happy with the performance of the system. Compared to actual raw performance of the storage servers running GlusterFS, it starts to look more sensible to run DRBD and single NFS server with all the other GlusterFS servers (currently 3 servers) waiting in hot-standby role.

Our workload is highly read oriented and usually deals with small files and I'd be happy to use "eventually consistent" system as long as a client can request sync for a single file if needed (that is, client is prepared to wait until the file has been successfully stored in the backend storage). I'd even accept a system where such "sync" requires querying the state of the file via some other way than POSIX `fdatasync()`. File metadata such as modification times is not important, only filename and the contents.

I'm currently aware of possible candidates and the problems each one currently has:

- GlusterFS: overall performance is pretty poor in practice, performance goes down while adding new servers/bricks.
- Ceph: highly complex to configure/administrate, POSIX compatibility sacrifices performance a lot as far as I know.
- MooseFS: partially obfuscated open source (huge dumps of internally written code published seldomly with intentionally lost patch history), documentation leaves lots to desire.
- SeaweedFS: pretty simple design and supposedly high performance, future of this project is unclear because pretty much all code is written and maintained by Chris Lu -  what happens if he no longer writes any code? Unclear if the "Filer" component supports no single point of failure.

I know that [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) prevents ever having truly consistent and always available system. Is there any good system for distributed file system where writes must be durable, but read performance is really good and the system has no single point of failure?

Comment: BeeGFS looks interesting: https://www.beegfs.io/ - does somebody have real world experience with it?

Comment: Ugh.. BeeGFS has really weird license (https://www.beegfs.io/docs/BeeGFS_EULA.txt) which probably would not hold in court but I wouldn't want to be the first one to try. At first reading, it seems that nobody should touch this software in real world production use.

Comment: It appears that you limit yourself to open source file systems. There might be business reasons for it, but there are good commercial systems (software-defined and/or appliance-based). You say POSIX-like, so NFS appears to be a possibility. There are many highly available, highly performant commercial storage systems that might fit. I will not name them all here (because I work for one of them). The key point is: You should consider not limiting yourself to open source for something like file systems and storage.

Comment: My experience with closed source vendors has been bad enough to avoid working with them unless absolutely necessary. I'm qualified to debug the issues by myself if I have the source (and sometimes without the source but I try to avoid that). Closed source works until you hit some obscure edge case that is too rare for the vendor to care. Then you either throw money towards vendor to make it more interesting or start to look for alternative for major subsystem.

Comment: You can also try looking into GFS2, OCFS2, and OrangeFS. Some of those are shared-disk, so you'll need to get some shared disks that are more fault tolerant - perhaps unlike the filesystem, those could be commercial.

Comment: If I trusted any shared disk system to never fail, I obviously would not need a no-single-point-of-failure system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Chris Lu working on SeaweedFS. There are plans to commercialize it. (By adding more advanced features.)

The filer does not have simple point of failure, you can have multiple filer instances. The filer store can be any key-value store. If you need no SPOF, you can use Cassandra, Redis cluster, CockroachDB, TiDB, or Etcd. Or you can add your own key-value store option, which is pretty easy.

Comment: About Filer: does Filer have any in-memory caches? Is it safe to run Filer instances on multiple servers with any given client connecting only one of them and all Filer processes sharing one key-value store (e.g. Cassandra or Redis)? If this is safe, is this syncronized or eventually consistent setup? Is there any way a client can wait for syncronized status for a given file?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Filer has some short-TTLed cache, but basically stateless. It's just like a stateless web server, which you can have multiple instances running. There are no locks. The last one operating on the filer store wins. For mysql/postgres filer store, there are transactions for renaming a folder.